# Flux to lower solder ball melting point

Tags: soldering, temperature, reflow, flux, bga

Is there any such flux? I find the balls on BGAs very hard on my home made oven.

From what I gather, mixing up solder types in order to lower the melting point is not the best idea, especially when the PCBs are to be used over wide temperature ranges and somewhat vibratory environments.

Comment: The alloy used to make the solder determines the melting point, not the flux.

Comment: All flux does is to clean and remove impurities.

Comment: You could replace them with balls made of leaded solder if you're not going to sell the  final device commercially, but it might be easier to upgrade the oven.

Comment: Use proper [solder paste](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/solder/262?s=N4IgTCBcDaIM4HsA2ATApgJwAQAcCGcALmiALoC%2BQA).  You can try tooth paste if you already massed up the board with flux. :)

Comment: @brhans that statement could better stand inside an answer.

Comment: @jay Could you expand on what a proper solder paste would be in this case and why ?

Comment: It would depend on your application and preference, proper to your application. But, using flux and some "mixing up solder types" is not going to be the answer. Did you check the DigiKey link? I had to try three different types, but ended in a lower melting point one, because it was easier to work with. Once you get it, keep those in the refrigerator.